# Setting Sitecore context language / Commerce price group from cookie

Tags: pipelines, session-state, ucommerce

Typically I would go into Global.asax.cs and add the code to set context language / culture and commerce price group / currency from a cookie (if available) in the session_start event.

I see multiple posts which do not recommend altering global.asax now for Sitecore and use pipelines instead.

I see a pipeline for SessionEnd in showconfig.aspx - but none for SessionStart - would you know where I should add this? 
I also saw this: https://sitecorejohn.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/overriding-sitecores-logic-to-determine-the-context-language/ but this would execute on every http request.

I could check if session exists and only them execute the code, (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308613/sitecore-session-started-pipeline) but it would still run the check on every http request anyhow? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, both Sitecore and uCommerce take care of cookies on their own.
All i needed to do was set the language / price group in the context when the user triggered this change.
The cookie got saved automatically.
On starting a new session, both cookies were loaded up automatically by Sitecore and the uCommerce libraries!